# 8th wall Image Target Not tracking image

Tags: 8thwall-xr, 8thwall-web

I have downloaded 8th wall web starter project from [github](https://github.com/8thwall/web/tree/master/examples/aframe/flyer). I am trying to run flyer demo locally.

Flyer demo index.html, I have replaced app key with newly created web project with 8th wall console.

Next, code below is used to achieve image target functionality

```
<!-- Note: "name:" must be set to the name of the image target uploaded to the 8th Wall Console -->
    <a-entity
      xrextras-named-image-target="name: video-target"
      xrextras-play-video="video: #jelly-video; thumb: #jelly-thumb; canstop: true"
      geometry="primitive: plane; height: 1; width: 0.79;">
    </a-entity>

    <!-- Note: "name:" must be set to the name of the image target uploaded to the 8th Wall Console -->
    <a-entity xrextras-named-image-target="name: model-target">
      <!-- Add a child entity that can be rotated independently of the image target. -->
      <a-entity xrextras-one-finger-rotate gltf-model="#jelly-glb"></a-entity>
    </a-entity>
```

So in order to make above code work, I have uploaded two image from images folder inside flyer demo to 8th wall console with name mentioned in above code. When I am running this, image target is not detecting for both the images.

When I saw the documentation on the internet as well as [here](https://www.8thwall.com/docs/web/#image-targets), I found that when you upload image target on 8th wall console, there is option to save and Enable however when uploading I can not see Enable option. Is this the reason image target is not working or do I need to publish 8th wall web app which include pricing to make this image target work?

Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code snippet, the xrextras-named-image-target component is looking for image targets named "video-target" and "model-target".  Make sure these strings match the names of the image targets uploaded to the console.

Additionally, make sure the image targets are set to "Load Automatically".  If not, edit the image target, check the "load automatically" and save the image target.

Comment: strange name is same but load automatically resolved the issue but I have tried this option previously also it was not working. One more query, as per documentation only five images are possible to load automatically how do we load more than 5 then?

Comment: To have more than 5 active at once (which is only currently supported if SLAM is disabled, see https://www.8thwall.com/docs/web/#image-target-quantities), you can call `XR8.XrController.configure()` and pass a list of image targets you'd like active.  For example:  ```XR8.XrController.configure({imageTargets: ['img1', 'img2', 'img3', 'img4', 'img5', 'img6']})```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same isue, and it returns an error in the editor wit the XR8.Controller line.

```
  <a-scene
  landing-page
  xrextras-loading
  xrextras-runtime-error
  xrweb="disableWorldTracking: true"
  XR8.XrController.configure({disableWorldTracking: true})
  XR8.XrController.configure({imageTargets: ['advImg', 'anssImg', 'ar1Img', 'ar2Img', 'ar3Img', 'ds1Img', 'ds2Img', 'ds3Img', 'egImg', 'exjImg', 'jaImg', 'jr1Img', 'jr2Img', 'jr3Img', 'jvt1Img', 'jvt2Img', 'jvt3Img', 'lecImg', 'ow1Img', 'ow2Img', 'ow3Img', 'rb1Img', 'rb2Img', 'rb3Img', 'svImg']})
>
```

The line about disableWorldTracking doesn't return an error, but I can only see 5 image targets are active in the debugging mode, despite the world tracking has been disabled.